# Simplified parameter null validation not working

Tags: .net-5, c#-9.0

Today I have updated my .net core 3.1 projects to .net 5. I was full of anticipation to use the Simplified parameter null validation but this is not working as expected. Any idea why ?

```
public void DoSomethingCool(string coolString!)
{
    // proceed to do some cool things
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This feature never went beyond [the discussion stage](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/2145). On September 10 2020, Mads Torgersen changed its milestone from `9.0 Candidate` to `10.0 Candidate`. The long and somewhat heated conversation shows that this isn't such a simple feature to implement without side effects